# Sharing variables using event object in html/jscript

Tags: jquery

I have two functions as follows. Is there a way to access the variable "result" in the top function using "e" when I am not allowed to modify the bottom function? Here, the 'add' event is auto triggered by the button click.

```
elem.addEventListener('add',function (e) {
    // need to do something with the variable "result"      
},true);

$(#myButton).click(function(evt) {
       var result = myFunction();
       if (result != null) {
       doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: declare result before `elem.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Frist of is this javascript or jQuery? lol just javascript do this:
Please note the javascript event listener is looking for an add event and not a click.

```
elem.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    var result=myFunction();
    if(result!==NULL)doSomething(); 
},true);
```

using a jQuery library:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
       var result=myFunction();
       if(result!==NULL)doSomething();
});
```

Passing variables using parameters:

```
var variable=2;//send an int
myFunction(variable);
myFunction('send a string');
variable===true;//send a boolean
myFunction(variable); 

myFunction(passedOver){
    console.log(passedOver);
}
```